# One to One Choice Field Django

Tags: python, django

So I have a Plant Model and a Sensor Model. Between them is a One To One realationship. When I want to add a new Plant, I want the Form to show me only the 'unused' Sensors as choices(those who have no realtionship with a plant yet.). I have tried multiple ways but I cant't figure out how to make it work

I have tried adding functionality to the AddPlant Form by checking all the sensors and adding the unused ones to a CHOICE tuple. After that I added a sensor ChoiceField with the CHOICE tuple as choices. It worked, but every time I wanted to add a new sensor to the database, I had to save the forms.py file to see the sensor being added to the Choices in the AddPlant form.

forms.py

```py
 class AddPlant(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Plant
        fields = (
                'name',
                'photo',
                'type_plant',
            )

    def __init__(self,CHOICES, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddPlant, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['sensor'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES)
```

models.py

```py
class Sensor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Plant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path, blank=True, null=True)
    sensor = models.OneToOneField(Sensor, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=False,)
    type_plant = models.ForeignKey('TypePlant', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    status = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```py
@login_required
def add_plant(request):

    if len(Plant.objects.all()) >= len(Sensor.objects.all()):

        return redirect('/account/add_plant/error_add_sensor')

    CHOICES = ()
    used_sensors = []
    for plant in Plant.objects.all():
        used_sensors.append(plant.sensor)

    for sensor in Sensor.objects.all():
        if sensor not in used_sensors:
            CHOICES += ((sensor.name, sensor.name),)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = AddPlant(request.POST,request.FILES, CHOICES)

        if form.is_valid():
            plant = form.save()
            plant.photo = form.cleaned_data['photo']
            for sensor in Sensor.objects.all():
                if sensor.name == form.cleaned_data['sensor']:
                    plant.sensor = sensor
            plant.save()
            return redirect('/account/add_plant/confirmation')
        else:
            return redirect('account:error_add_plant')


    form = AddPlant(CHOICES)
    return render(request, 'account/add_plant.html', {'form': form})
```

Error message with this code:

> 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'

The code stops at if form.is_valid():

Full Traceback:

```
AttributeError at /account/add_plant/
'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://192.168.43.92:1234/account/add_plant/
Django Version: 2.2
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'
Exception Location: /home/adam_suma/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py in value_from_datadict, line 385
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.7
Python Path:    
['/home/adam_suma/Lenautech',
 '/usr/lib/python36.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/home/adam_suma/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 6 Jun 2019 08:29:54 +0000
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
/home/adam_suma/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py in inner
            response = get_response(request) …
▶ Local vars
/home/adam_suma/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) …
▶ Local vars
/home/adam_suma/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
/home/adam_suma/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py in _wrapped_view
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
/home/adam_suma/Lenautech/account/views.py in add_plant
        if form.is_valid(): …
▶ Local vars
/home/adam_suma/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py in is_valid
        return self.is_bound and not self.errors …
▶ Local vars
/home/adam_suma/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py in errors
            self.full_clean() …
▶ Local vars
/home/adam_suma/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py in full_clean
        self._clean_fields() …
▶ Local vars
/home/adam_suma/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py in _clean_fields
                value = field.widget.value_from_datadict(self.data, self.files, self.add_prefix(name)) …
▶ Local vars
/home/adam_suma/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py in value_from_datadict
        upload = super().value_from_datadict(data, files, name) …
▶ Local vars
/home/adam_suma/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py in value_from_datadict
        return files.get(name) …
▶ Local vars
Request information
USER
admin
```

Comment: Please show full traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've changed the signature of the form's init method by putting CHOICES as the first positional argument. That means that the default args - data and files - are now expected to come *after* the choices, not before. The error is happening because your choices tuple is being taken as the data argument.

Really you should avoid changing the signature like that. You should get choices from the kwargs, passing it as a keyword rather than positionally. Also, you shouldn't use all-caps for argument names; that is for constants.

So:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    choices = kwargs.pop('choices', [])
    super(AddPlant, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['sensor'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choices)
```

and in the view:

```
form = AddPlant(request.POST, request.FILES, choices=CHOICES)
```

But note, all this seems a bit unnecessary. For a field that takes it choices from another model, you use a ModelChoiceField. You want the choices to be all unused sensors, so simply set that as the queryset; no need to override `__init__` at all, and no need for all that complex logic in the view.

```
class AddPlant(forms.ModelForm):

    sensor = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Sensor.objects.filter(plant=None))

    class Meta:
        model = Plant
        fields = (
                'name',
                'photo',
                'type_plant',
                'sensor'
            )
```

Also note, however you do this you *do* need to have 'sensor' in the fields list, otherwise it won't be saved.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't really know how the ModelChoiceField worked.